# Why Is blender rig not matching up with fingures?

Tags: rigging

I made a full body rig and all of it works fine, however for some reason both hands are having issues with the figures this is how I have the rig set up[image: enter image description here.]

but when i move a finger bone it does this:

[image]

it seems as if each bone moves a random finger could somebody help me with this I am newer?

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: The preferred way to assign mesh parts to individual bones is to use "weights", which are vertex groups with the same name as the bones you want to assign mesh to. But for that to work, you need to have each bone correctly named (especially mirrored bones), each vertex group to be created and with the correct name, and each vertex group to be correctly assigned to the right mesh parts. The fastest way to do the latter is to parent the mesh object to the armature object using Ctrl P > Parent to Armature "With Automatic Weights". If the previous steps were done correctly, this should work fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am miss understanding however I've named everything correctly and I still get the same result. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: Parent With Automatic Weights will probably fail for the hand, you probably need to do it through the Vertex Groups list and the Assign button, but first remove all these vertices from all groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Automatic Weights* will struggle with the hands. You probably need to do it manually: First thing remove the vertices from all the vertex groups:

[image]

Then select each part and parent to the correct vertex group:

[image]

Comment: This works thank you so much!

Comment: but why would it fail though?

Comment: because the faces are too close to each other but I can't tell the technical reason why it makes things harder to calculate?