# Why the armature modifies the whole render?

Tags: animation, armature

Im trying to make a cutout box animation , i placed bones and assigned them to their respective faces , but when i move one of the bones to move the face, the whole box is deformed .
What im doing wrong?
Thanks for your help this community is amazing.

[image]

Comment: Some vertices are not correctly assigned, see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301555/why-is-blender-rig-not-matching-up-with-fingures/301588?noredirect=1#comment521960_301588