# Painted weights on hand is messed up, spikey looking

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

I just finished weight panting the hand on this model and I thought it seemed good, but when I moved the hand or arm bone the hand didn't follow entirely. It spiked out like so:

[image: hand]

I made sure "Auto Normalize" was on and that the individual fingers were properly painted and the weights didn't bleed onto the other fingers. I selected each finger bone individually and painted around them with a weight of 0. What would cause it to glitch out like this? Is there an easy fix? Having to repaint the fingers would be a pain in the ass.

Comment: Probably those vertices have weights on other bones than the ones from hand and fingers?

Comment: See my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301555/why-is-blender-rig-not-matching-up-with-fingures/301588#301588 painting with a weight of 0 is not enough, it will just remove the vertices from the selected vertex group but not all vertex groups

Comment: Yea it seems that was the case, I couldn't see the problem in Weight Paint mode, only Edit Mode. After further inspection it seems other bones also have the same problem, but not as badly. Is there anything I can do to prevent this mess from happening next time? Or do I just have to weight paint more carefully?